# Intersection of two BDDs using CUDD

Tags: binary-decision-diagram, cudd

I would like to find intersection of two BDDs for the following two Boolean functions:

```
F=A'B'C'D'=1
G=A XOR B XOR C XOR D=1
```

Here is my code:

```
 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char filename[30];
        DdManager *gbm; /* Global BDD manager. */
        gbm = Cudd_Init(0,0,CUDD_UNIQUE_SLOTS,CUDD_CACHE_SLOTS,0); /* Initialize a new BDD manager. */
        DdNode *bdd, *var, *tmp_neg, *tmp,*f,*g;
        int i;
        bdd = Cudd_ReadOne(gbm); /*Returns the logic one constant of the manager*/
        Cudd_Ref(bdd); /*Increases the reference count of a node*/

        for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
          var = Cudd_bddIthVar(gbm,i); /*Create a new BDD variable*/
          tmp_neg = Cudd_Not(var); /*Perform NOT Boolean operation*/
          tmp = Cudd_bddAnd(gbm, tmp_neg, bdd); /*Perform AND Boolean operation*/
          Cudd_Ref(tmp);
          Cudd_RecursiveDeref(gbm,bdd);
          f = tmp;
        }

        for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
          var = Cudd_bddIthVar(gbm,i); /*Create a new BDD variable*/
          tmp = Cudd_bddXor(gbm, var, bdd); /*Perform AND Boolean operation*/
          Cudd_Ref(tmp);
          Cudd_RecursiveDeref(gbm,bdd);
          g = tmp;
        }
        bdd= Cudd_bddIntersect(gbm,f,g);/*Intersection between F and G */
        bdd = Cudd_BddToAdd(gbm, bdd); /*Convert BDD to ADD for display purpose*/
    print_dd (gbm, bdd, 2,4); /*Print the dd to standard output*/
    sprintf(filename, "./bdd/graph.dot"); /*Write .dot filename to a string*/
    write_dd(gbm, bdd, filename);  /*Write the resulting cascade dd to a file*/
    Cudd_Quit(gbm);
    return 0; 
}
```

And here is the result I got:

```
DdManager nodes: 7 | DdManager vars: 4 | DdManager reorderings: 0 | DdManager memory: 8949888 
: 3 nodes 2 leaves 2 minterms
ID =  0xaa40f   index = 0   T = 0           E =  1        

0---  1
```

As you can see here the intersection gives A=0 and don't cares for B,C and D. I was expecting values of A,B,C and D that satifies both F and G. But clearly A=0 is not the solution for both F and G. For example someone can choose A=0,B=1 which gives 0 for function F. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This reply comes awfully late, but just to close the issue, the problem is that the last operand to both `Cudd_bddAnd` and `Cudd_bddXor` is `bdd` instead of `f` or `g`.  Of course, both `f` and `g` should be properly initialized (the way `bdd` is currently initialized).  Fixing the code this way will also take care of the multiple dereferences of `bdd`, which are going to cause grief should garbage collection kick in.

Also, `Cudd_bddIntersect` does not compute the AND of two BDDs, but a function that implies the AND.  It's used when one wants a witness to the nonemptiness of the conjunction of two BDDs without computing the whole result (and then possibly extracting a witness from it).

Finally, `bdd` is used as both operand to `Cudd_BddToAdd` and as destination for the return value.  This is guaranteed to "leak" BDD nodes.